# Javascript - swapping data in variables - move and replace

Tags: javascript, string, variables, replace

I am looking for a simple way to move and replace some data with javascript.  Here's an example...  I always have 2 variables.  Each has a word, followed by another word inside `<p>` tags, like this...
`x="Hello<p>World</p>"`  and `y="Goodbye<p>People</p>"`
Step 1) I no longer need the data and the `<p>` tags in the x variable. Strip that from the variable so it becomes  `x="Hello"`
Step 2) I need to swap the x variable with the first part of the y variable.  So the end result will be...
`x="Goodbye"` and `y="Hello<p>People</p>"`

Comment: Why don't you store all this in four different variables and compose them? Like `Hello ${name}` and `Goodbye ${name}`

Comment: So what specifically gives you troubles here? What's the context? Do you have any code examples of attempting to solve this?

Comment: Well, I'm not experienced with javascript, but I would start with `x = x.substring(0, x.indexOf('<p>'));`  That would make `x="Hello"`  But how do I get the 1st part of Y then swap them

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var x="Hello<p>World</p>";
    var y="Goodbye<p>People</p>";

     x = x.slice(0,x.indexOf("<p>"));
    var z= y.slice(0,y.indexOf("<p>"));

    y = y.replace(z,x);
    x = z;

    console.log("x=" + x + " y=" + y);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many, many ways to do things like this.  The following uses regex plus string.replace.

```js
let x="Hello<p>World</p>";
let y="Goodbye<p>People</p>";
console.log('x starts as '+x);
console.log('y starts as '+y);

const r=/^(.*)<p>(.*)<\/p>/;

const xresult = r.exec(x);
//xresult = ["Hello<p>World</p>", "Hello", "World"]
x=xresult [1];
console.log('x now equals '+x);

const yresult = r.exec(y);
//yresult = ["Goodbye<p>People</p>", "Goodbye", "People"]

//now swap
y = y.replace(yresult[1],x);
x = yresult[1];

console.log(`x = ${x} y = ${y}`);
```

Note that this is a literal answer to your question.  This may not be exactly what you are looking for as it really depends on context.  i.e. is this just a string or is it a structured bit of HTML you are wanting to modify (in which case the DOM API is probably the better approach).

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be easier than I thought.  Just used some substrings...

```
x = x.substring(0, x.indexOf('<p>'));
z = y.substring(0, y.indexOf('<p>'));
y = y.substring(y.indexOf("<p>"));
y=x+y;
x=z;
```

Comment: If anyone can make it even simpler, please share.  thanks.